# strictly positive element

Tags: operator-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

If $A$ is a non-unital separable $C^*$ algebra,does there exist a strictly positive idempotent element in $A$ ?

Comment: Not even true for commutative ones? These are isomorphic to $C_0(X)$ for some locally compact space, but the only idempotent there is $0$, which definately is not strictly positive. I think you are missing some assumption?

Comment: Stricly positive elements are usually very far away from idempotent.

Comment: @Munk your remark is justified in that this can never happen, but note that there are more idempotents in $C_0(X)$ if $X$ has some compact components.

Comment: @s.harp Yes you are absolutely right, the indicator functions to the components would give examples, thanks for the corrections.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A strictly positive element $e$ in $A$ satisfies $\overline{ eAe}=A$. If $e$ is an idempotent, then $e$ would be a unit for $A$, which you are assuming non-unital.